# Same unit tests for .NET 2.0 / Silverlight / Windows Phone 7 projects

Tags: .net, silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-7, nunit

I have a plenty of tests for my .NET 2.0 project (I use NUnit for them).

Recently, I ported the project to Silverlight 3 and plan to build WP7 version from the same code base, too. Of course, I am interested in running the same tests against Silverlight / WP7 versions.

I setup [nunit-silverlight](http://code.google.com/p/nunit-silverlight/) for the task but soon discovered that following constructs are not supported:

```
[TestCaseSource("ArrayOfStrings")]
public void TestTheArg(string arg)
{
    ...
}
```

because there is no support for `TestCaseSource` attribute in nunit-silverlight.

Should I migrate to other testing framework or is there any possibility to make nunit-silverlight run the same tests?

If I should migrate then please recommend a testing framework that can be used to run the same tests against .NET 2.0 / Silverlight / WP7 frameworks.

Comment: Have you trid standart `TestCase` attribute?

Comment: yes, but it's inconvenient in my case. btw, TestCaseSource is standard too.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing precisely what `TestCaseSource` does, I would say, it's probably not available due to the limited reflection API for Windows Phone.

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) contains a version of MS Test that can be used on Windows Phone. So you could migrate your tests there, and they *should* be compatible with Silverlight / .NET 2.0.

But I personally haven't tried testing the Silverlight Toolkit implementation against other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. obviously `TestCaseSource` is not supported in the nunit-silverlight, you can use the TestCaseAttribute instead of it.